# ORA-00904: "DISCIPLINE"."SPORT_NO": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
  sport_name
from 
  GAMES.sport
where 
  sport.sport_no = discipline.SPORT_NO;
```

HELP please, the table and column do exist in my database

Comment: where is discipline table in your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
      SPORT_NAME
FROM
      GAMES.SPORT,
      GAMES.DISCIPLINE
WHERE
      SPORT.SPORT_NO = DISCIPLINE.SPORT_NO;
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins in the `where` clause. Use the "modern" explicit `JOIN` syntax that was introduced with SQL 92.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  sport_name
from 
  SPORT
  inner join 
     DISCIPLINE
        on SPORT.sport_no = DISCIPLINE.SPORT_NO;
```

`SPORT.sport_no` is a primary key of `SPORT` table
and
`DISCIPLINE.SPORT_NO` is a foreign key in `DISCIPLINE` table